# passing array list from model to script in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array list that I want passing this array to a script(instead of `tags: ["tag1","tag2"]`). Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

`model.rb`

```
  attr_writer :tag_names

  after_save :assign_tags

  def tag_names
    @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
  end

  private
  def assign_tags
    if @tag_names
      self.tags = @tag_names.split(/ /).map do |name|
        Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
    end
  end
```

`model/_form.html.erb`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#e20").select2({
            tags: ["tag1","tag2"],
            tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use .join(',') instead - and then print out the Model.tag_names on tags: ["tag1", "tag2"] with [<%= Model.tag_names %> (not sure about erb syntax right now)

Comment: I generate the array by `Tag.pluck(:name)`, but when I pass this array to JS, I have [&quot;name1&quot;, &quot;name2&quot;] instead of ["name1","name2"]. I use `tags: <%= Tag.pluck(:name) %>` erb syntax. Do you know the problem?

Comment: i think you should use **array = Tag.all.pluck(:name)** and then use this array variable. and in place of **Tag.all** you can use your own query whatever you want

Comment: or to so solve the &quot;  <%= Tag.pluck(:name).html_safe %>