# read column from database and add to array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table in database, name of table is `tags` and This table has 2 columns: 1.name, 2.count. I want read first column and add to an array and seprate names with `","`. I use below code:

```
@list = Array.new
temp = Tag.all
@list || temp.map(&:name).join(",")
```

I want create list like below sample:

```
"name1","name2",..,"namen"
```

I want pass this array to a javascript. I asked a [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577429/passing-array-list-from-model-to-script-in-rails); I want create array type like this: ["name1","name2"]. How can I convert @list to this type?

Answer (score 0):

[`Tag.pluck(:name)`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) will create an array of names from the `tags` database

---

To add to an [array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html), you'll want to do this:

```
@list ||= Tag.all.map(&:name)
@list << Tag.find 15 # -> if you wanted to add to the array
```

Arrays are already joined with a `,` - you don't need to do that. If you wanted a string of names which is joined by `,`, you'll want to convert the array to a string first

Comment: I want pass this array to a `javascript`. I asked a [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577429/passing-array-list-from-model-to-script-in-rails); I want create array like this: `["name1","name2"]`. How can I convert `@list` to this type?

Comment: If you use the `pluck` method, it will create that array for you. You can then pass the array to JS. I think you're asking the wrong question

Comment: I use `pluck`, but when I pass this to JS, I have `[&quot;name1&quot;, &quot;name2&quot;]` instead of `["name1","name2"]`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have rails 3.2~> then use

```
Tag.pluck(:name)
```

and if your rails old then use

```
@list = Tag.all.map(&:name).join(",")
```